# Where to add Annotations in ASP.Net MVC 4 Application with POCO objects

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a modest application, I started by creating a Domain Layer where I defined my POCO objects, then I created a Data Access Layer that persist those Domain objects to database using EF Code First. Now I need to an a UI to this project and I have created an MVC 4 project, I need to create a strongly typed view so I need a model to pass to the view.

My question is where do I need to recreate my domain objects in the Model folder so I can add Data annotations to them. For example, I have a Customer

```
public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public int RetailerId { get; set; }
    public string  CustomerName { get; set; }
    public string CustomerEmail { get; set; }
    public int PointsBalance { get; set; }
    public decimal CashBalance { get; set; }

    public ICollection<LoyaltyCard> LoyaltyCards { get; set; }
    public virtual Retailer BusinessName { get; set; }
}
```

And a retailer object like so:

```
public class Retailer
    {
        public int RetailerId { get; set; }
        public string BusinessName { get; set; }
        public string EmailsAddress { get; set; }
        public int PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Location> BusinessLocations { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Reward> Rewards { get; set; }
        public Industry Industry { get; set; }
    }
```

Should I add annotations to my current domain objects in the domain layer - if I do that does that not violate the aim of making the domain objects POCO objects. Or should I re-create my domain objects in the Model folder? - would that not be a duplicate. If you have any pointers please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't **recreate** them, instead you should create models that contain only the fields you need, that way you can add your annotations to them.

You say that it's duplication, but in reality it's **separation of concerns**. The less the UI knows about your POCOs the better (in an ideal world, your UI wouldn't even know about them, they'd retrieve instances of the model via some Business Logic Layer/API.

For example, take a look at the `CustomerViewModel` below. Notice there's some properties missing? Well I know it's a crude example, but you might not actually want to be entering all the properties when adding a new customer/displaying them, so here's a trimmed down version ideal for that purpose:

```
public class CustomerViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int RetailerId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string  CustomerName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string CustomerEmail { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the point where ViewModels come in. These models are used to display data from your domain models in a view, but only contain the properties you need to display a view. You can add data annotations to these properties which will take care of the validation.

I recommend using [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) to map your domain models to ViewModels.

Comment: Thanks, let me checkout Automapper. The View model classes can be created inside the default Model folder in ASP.Net? or do I need to create ViewModel folder?

Comment: @ValOkafor functionally it doesn't matter where you place them. I think it's better to create a ViewModels folder if you have your domain models in the Models folder, but if you have the domain models in a different assembly, the Models folder is just fine.